# Call objects inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to call this code below inside to array of objects. 
I'm getting an error of `Unexpected token` How can I fix it?

```
const sharedTabs = {
  key: 'all',
  title: 'All',
  icon: '',
  content: (
    <DataTable
      rowKey={isAll => isAll.ticketId}
      dataSource={isAll}
      columns={columns}
      loading={state.loading}
      pagination={allPagination}
      onChange={handleTableChange}
    />
  ),
  count: allCount,
 }, {
  key: 'fastLane',
  title: 'Fastlane',
  icon: 'thunderbolt',
  content: (
    <DataTable
      rowKey={isFastlane => isFastlane.ticketId}
      dataSource={isFastlane}
      columns={columns}
      loading={state.loading}
      pagination={fastlanePagination}
      onChange={handleTableChange}
    />
  ),
  count: fastlaneCount,
};
```

I'm calling it like this. I just want to merge them so I don't need to declare it again if i have same objects to other tabs

```
const tabPanes = [ 
  sharedTabs,
  {
    key: 'resolvedToday',
    title: 'Resolved Today',
    icon: 'check-circle',
    content: (
      <DataTable
        rowKey={isResolved => isResolved.ticketId}
        dataSource={isResolved}
        columns={columns}
        loading={state.loading}
        pagination={resolvedTodayPagination}
        onChange={handleTableChange}
      />
    ),
    count: resolvedCount,
  },
];
```

Comment: After de declaration of `sharedTabs` there is a comma and a second object definition. I believe this is the unexpected token

Comment: You need to put the different objects inside an array, then use the spread operator to add them as a part of a new array

Comment: @GalAbra Thank you!!! This solves my problem. By the way, is it possible to have an order for each object so I can manage which will display first?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Arrays are already ordered, so you should have your expected behaviour